# Como utlizar o Data Binding Object do Spring para atributos em snake case mantendo o padrão da Java Naming Conventions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Olá, existe alguma forma de realizar o data binding de objetos no Spring usando snake case?

Por exemplo, suponhamos a seguinte request `GET` em um serviço `REST`:

> http://localhost:8080/foobar?foo_bar=example

Para o data binding do Spring funcione, na class Foobar o atributo deve ter o nome exato com o parâmetro da requisição, ou seja:

```java
public class FooBar {

    @NotBlank(message = "Campo 'foo_bar' não pode ser vazio")
    private String foo_bar;

}
```

Mas esse nome para o atributo não é aceitável de acordo com a ***Java Naming Conventions***.

Portanto, a classe ficaria da seguinte maneira:

```java
public class FooBar {

    @JsonProperty("foo_bar")
    @NotBlank(message = "Campo 'foo_bar' não pode ser vazio")
    private String fooBar;

}
```

Porém, dado o formato da requisição, o data binding do Spring não consegue realizar o bind.

Alguém sabe como manter a formalidade com a convenção e ao mesmo tempo fazer o bind funcionar?

Adendo: O RestController está com um método assim:

```java
@RequestMapping("/foobar")
public ResponseEntity<Object> foobar(@Validated FooBar fooBar, Errors errors) {

        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(fooBar);
    }
```

Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma boa idéia é criar um filtro que converta os valores de snake case para camel case (ou qualquer outro formato).

Esse filtro será executado para toda requisição, e irá tratar os parâmetros de acordo e repassar o request ao controller com os valores do request já formatados.

### **Falar é fácil! Mostre o código!**

`AppConfig.java`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.google.common.base.CaseFormat;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Filter snakeConverter() {
        return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

            @Override
            protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
                final Map<String, String[]> formattedParams = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

                for (String param : request.getParameterMap().keySet()) {
                    String formattedParam = CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, param);
                    formattedParams.put(formattedParam, request.getParameterValues(param));
                }

                filterChain.doFilter(new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                    @Override
                    public String getParameter(String name) {
                        return formattedParams.containsKey(name) ? formattedParams.get(name)[0] : null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
                        return Collections.enumeration(formattedParams.keySet());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
                        return formattedParams.get(name);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                        return formattedParams;
                    }
                }, response);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Agora vamos a explicação sobre o código acima:

A configuração no `snakeConverter` irá fazer a mágica acontecer:

O método `doFilterInternal` é executado sempre **antes** da requisição ser passada ao controller, desta forma nós estamos pegando todos os parâmetros passados, incluindo em um novo `Map` com os valores formatados em camel case, e encaminhando para frente através do `filterChain.doFilter`, que irá de fato encaminhar a requisição ao controller.

O `HttpServletRequestWrapper` envelopa o request e response, e retorna os valores que definimos em nosso novo mapa de parâmetros.

Segue a documentação do [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html)

Estou usando o [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) para converter de snake case para camel case, se estiver usando Maven basta incluir esta dependência no seu `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

O código é completamente baseado no filtro criado pelo [azhawkes](https://gist.github.com/azhawkes/3db84b194b3e47423df2)

---

Utilizando o Restlet para fazer o teste em um controller simples:

Para a URL: http://localhost:8080/snakecase?foo_bar=123

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Notei que esta pergunta estava aberta no [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945172/binding-snake-case-request-parameters-to-a-spring-form/55330566#55330566), aproveitei e respondi ela também :)